# How do get only one row which is just less than a specified value in spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below -

```
Id,timestamp
100,1
200,2
300,3
400,4
500,5
600,6
```

And now I want to get only a single row whose value is just less than timestamp 5.
Equivalent sql query : `select * from table1 where id <5 order by timestamp desc limit 1.`

But in spark query I do not want to perform order by operation because our data size is too large , so it will take too much time.
Is it possible in spark to do the same without using order by?

Comment: Please add expected output. I believe there is an issue with your example (i.e. no id is < 5)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can run that SQL query right in spark:

```
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

spark.sql("select * from table1 where id <5 order by timestamp desc limit 1")
```

Beside that, you know that the `id` (I see you meant `timestamp`) is exactly 4:

```
dataframe.where("timestamp = 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct (you can use your query directly on a temporary view or `orderBy` + `limit`) none seems to address your main concern:

> But in Spark query I do not want to perform order by operation because our data size is too large , so it will take too much time. Is it possible in Spark to do the same without using order by?

Let's take a look what happens under the covers:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, 1), (200, 2), (300, 3), (400, 4), (500, 5), (600, 6)],
    ("id", "timestamp"))

df.filter("timestamp < 5").orderBy(df["timestamp"].desc()).limit(1).explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=1, orderBy=[timestamp#35L DESC NULLS LAST], output=[id#34L,timestamp#35L])
# +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(timestamp#35L) && (timestamp#35L < 5))
#    +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#34L,timestamp#35L]
```

As you can see there is no sort at all. Spark analyzed the plan, in place of full sort, applied `TakeOrderedAndProject`. In result it will take only top on record from every partition.

Operation is till linear in terms of the number of rows, but you don't have to worry a but full shuffle required to sort all records.

Conclusion? As long as limit value is small, there is nothing to worry about here (with large limits, things can get ugly).

Comment: val df = Seq(
  (100, 1),
  (200, 2),
  (300, 3),
  (400, 4),
  (500, 5),
  (600, 6)
)
And what if we do not want to create a dataframe , because data is too large. And data is stored in  Cassadra and we have to fetch only a single row which is just less than 5 (ts < 5) and in output result set we shoud get only one row whose timestamp value is just less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

In short: sort, filter by value < specified, pick the last element of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.filter("id<5").orderBy(f.col("timestamp").desc()).first()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I do not want to use order by clause. Because our data size is too large so order by will take too much time.
I just want to get a single row whose value should be less than 5(timestamp field). So output should be 400,4
rows are already sorted by timestamp in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `ordering` due to large dataframe size, consider using `reduce` to only get the max after filtering:

```
val df = Seq(
  (100, 1),
  (200, 2),
  (300, 3),
  (400, 4),
  (500, 5),
  (600, 6)
).toDF("id", "ts")

df.where($"ts" < 5).reduce( (acc, r) =>
  if (r.getAs[Int]("ts") > acc.getAs[Int]("ts")) r else acc
)
// res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [400,4]
```